# Calculation of Einstein theory: How to gauge condtion to cancel perturbation terms in xact

Tags: xact

I try to use the xAct Mathematica package for deal with the Einstein field equation in weak field. I can get

$R=-h^{ab}_{,ab}+\frac{\eta^{ab}}{2}\left[h^c_{c,ab}-\Delta h_{ab}\right]$,

Now, I want to introduce the condition $h^b_{a,b}-\frac12h^b_{b,a}=0$ to cancel the term $\frac{\eta^{ab}}{2}\left[h^c_{c,ab}-\Delta h_{ab}\right]$, but I know how to do it by Mathematica.

In fact, I try to use IndexRule[] to do it, but you know, this command is not very intelligent. For example, if we set IndexRule[$h^b_{a,b}-\frac12h^b_{b,a}$,0], computer can cancel all $h^b_{a,b}-\frac12h^b_{b,a}$ terms, but cannot cancel $h^c_{d,c}-\frac12h^c_{c,d}$ terms or $h^c_{d,ce}-\frac12h^c_{c,de}$ terms, and so on. I need cancel all terms, I know whether xact can do it or not?

Who can help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!